# Al iniciar la activity...cómo puedo hacer para el que cursor comience en el primer EditText?

Tags: android

Mi problema es que al iniciar la activity el cursor del teclado empieza en el tercer EditText como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna propiedad donde pueda ubicar el cursor en el primer EditText, osea, el que está alado del Spinner? y otra duda que tenía era si existe alguna propiedad para que una vez que se complete el campo de ese primer EditText, al presionar  la tecla  -->| del celular se pueda mover al EditText de alado y NO al que está debajo? Desde ya gracias!

Comment: Para colocar el foco en un EditText puedes hacerlo programaticamente así: `nombre_edittext.requestFocus();`

Comment: Funciono! muchas gracias